# How to select multiple li item using control key in jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Here i am selecting a single li item in one list  and on click of the add button the selected item will be moved to the next lsit

```
  $("#list3 li").click(function () {
                $("#list3 li").removeClass('clicked');
                $(this).addClass('clicked');

            });
$("#add").click(function () {
            $("#list3 li.clicked").removeClass("clicked").appendTo('#list4');
             });
```

and

```
 .clicked {
      border: 3px solid blue;

    }
```

Here i need to select multiple li items using the control key and if i click add button all the selected li items has to be moved to another list..Any suggestion?

Comment: what is the criteria to select multiple items?

Comment: multiple selection has to work only when i press control button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you need to select multiple items then you need to modify the code that unselects every item except the last one you clicked:

```
$("#list3 li").click(function (e) {
    // PLACED INSIDE CONDITIONAL
    if (!e.ctrlKey) {
        $("#list3 li").removeClass('clicked');
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');  // LINE MODIFIED
});
```

I also changed `addClass('clicked')` to `toggleClass('clicked')` so that you can also unselect items by clicking on them again. The rest of your code does not need to change.

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/pqF7b/)**.

Comment: but multiple selection has to work only when i press control button

Comment: @bala3569: What do you mean? What/where is the control button?

Comment: @bala3569: Works for me, see link.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#list3 li").click(function (e) {
    {
        if (!(e.metaKey)){
            $("#list3 li").removeClass('clicked');
        }
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
    });
```

e.metaKey works for apple (command) and windows/linux (control)

Comment: I don't know how much hand holding you need... but here's another JS Fiddle that shows that it works:
http://jsfiddle.net/HMn9U/1/

although the credit really should go to Jon. I merely suggested you use "metaKey" so that it is more compatible with other OSes

Comment: sorry.. my fiddle didn't faddle correctly. Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/HMn9U/2/